# From the tree structure get list

Tags: c#

I have a class CategoryModel in c#, which is an element of a tree:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameEng { get; set; }
    public string ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> ChildCategoriesIds { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public ICollection<string> ProductsIds { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameEng { get; set; }
}
```

The `ChildCategoriesIds` contains `Id` class `CategoryModel`. 
The `ProductsIds` contains `Id` class `Product`.

How proccesed data in new classes:

```
public class CategoryNew
{
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameEng { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UidName> ChildCategories { get; set; } = new List<UidName>();
    public IEnumerable<UidName> Products { get; set; } = new List<UidName>();
}

public class UidName
{
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameEng { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The method that will convert the List<CategoryModel> to List<CategoryNew>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify own constructor for `CategoryNew`, which will take as an argument object of class `CategoryModel`, in which you will set all properties of `CategoryNew` based on values of properties of `CategoryModel`:

```
public CategoryNew(CategoryModel cm){
    // set properties
}
```

Then your method would be:

```
public List<CategoryNew> ConverModelToNew(List<CategoryModel> lstCatModel){
    List<CategoryNew> lstCatNew = new List<CategoryNew>();

    foreach(var item in lstCatModel){
        lstCatNew.Add(new CetagoryNew(item));
    }

    return lstCatNew;
}
```

Comment: The method that will convert the List<CategoryModel> to List<CategoryNew> whith child categories and products

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to convert one set of object to another set of objects.
First of all, I believe categories shouldl inherit `UidName` so you will memory more efficiently by reducing duplicate objects.

```
public class CategoryNew: UidName
{
    public IEnumerable<CategoryNew> ChildCategories { get; set; } = new List<CategoryNew>();
    public IEnumerable<UidName> Products { get; set; } = new List<UidName>();
}

public class UidName
{
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameEng { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

// first run to create products
var newProducts = products.Select(p => new UidName {
    Uid = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    NameEnd = p.NameEng
}).ToArray();

// second run to create categories with products
var newCategories = categories.Select(c => new CategoryNew {
    Uid = c.Id,
    Name = c.Name,
    NameEng = c.NameEng,
    IsDeleted = (bool?)null,  //TODO
    Products = newProducts.Where(p => c.ProductIds.Contains(p.Uid))
                          .ToList()
}).ToArray();

// last run find sub categories
foreach(var category in newCategories) {
    var oldCategory = categories.First(c => c.Id == category.Uid);
    category.ChildCategories = newCategories.Where(c => oldCategory.ChildCategoriesIds.Contains(c.Uid))
                                            .ToArray();
}
```